# Шестиугольник с фоном

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать блок в виде шестиугольника. На заднем фоне  многоугольника  будут разные изображения.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @KAGGDesign, не выйдет. Фон не будет отображаться в верхней и нижней частях фигуры из за того, что они сделаны с помощью псевдоэлементов

Comment: Что-то я не пойму что надо сделать. Стрелочки указывают на скошенные углы, но в итоге это 8-миугольник. Или надо сделать что-то типа блоков с логотипами по бокам?

Comment: Господи, покажите мне, где там шестиугольник? Тоже вижу только 8.

Comment: ну во первых моюю тему правили  я изначально писал про 8-угольник 

и да благодаря нижнему ответу) все получилось) всем спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `linear-gradient`.

```css
.wapper {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

.hexagon {
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 15px, white 0) top left,
  linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 15px, white 0) top right,
  linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 15px, white 0) bottom right,
  linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 15px, white 0) bottom left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class='wapper'>
  <div class='hexagon'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все гуд) спасибо))

Answer (score 5):

Я бы делал с помощью [масок в SVG](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-masks/).

```css
.hexagon {
  /* Выравняем содержимое блока поцентру */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  position: relative;
  
  /* Зададим нужные параметры блоку */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Сделаем svg "фоном" */
.hexagon svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon">
  <!-- Создаём фигуру с фоном -->
  <svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 12 12" style="enable-background:new 0 0 12 12;">
  
    <!-- Создаём маску для "фона" с помощью координат -->
    <mask id="mask">
      <path fill="white" d="M12,9 6,12 0.5,9 0.5,3 6,0 12,3z"/>
    </mask>
    
    <!-- Применяем маску к нужному нам "фону" -->
    <image mask="url(#mask)" xlink:href="https://images2.popmeh.ru/upload/img_cache/a97/a97da46a204e5b28b95f5645a68cc918_ce_3840x1536x0x399_cropped_1920x768.jpg" height="12" />
  </svg>
  
  <!-- Можно ещё добавить любое содержимое -->
  Просто космос ._.
</div>
```

Comment: @СергійЧуйко и у меня не получается, по причине, что ваш сайт не в сети сейчас.

Comment: Ваш метод не подошел(